# Attractor Trajectories

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations, dynamical-systems, fixed-point-theorems

Knowing dynamical equations, one can straightforwardly solve them algebraically to find the fixed points and then anticipate the field behavior near them by finding the eigenvalues. But there are some trajectories that appear as an attractor paths i.e. draw inwards neighbor field flows and force them to follow a same path. 
Is there any systematic method to find such attractor tracks? 
For example, Let's the equations be
$$
\frac{dx}{dt}=x^2 + x y^2  \; and\;  \frac{dy}{dt}=y  + 2 x^2 - y^2 
$$
Then the fixed points are $(0,0)$, $(0,1)$ & $(-1,-1)$ where you can see their  special behavior in the below phase portrait diagram .

[image: phase portrait]
[phase portrait](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hvES9.png)

But one also recognizes the other behavior in which the flows try to reach two particular trajectories in the upper half plain. What is the equation of such attractor trajectories in general? That is the question.

Comment: Really difficult to follow what you may want, you may want to give some details to get meaningful answer. Also, not quite right "one can straightforwardly solve them algebraically"... instead very difficult in general.

Comment: See my edited answer

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, from looking at the trajectories of that system, you have got the impression that some trajectories are kind of *converging* to a specific trajectory, and you want to know what that trajectory is.

The problem is, you can't guess the general behavior of a dynamical system just by looking at its stream-plot in a *finite* interval. But before discussing this matter, let's take a look at the system's equation:
$$\begin{align}\dot{x}&=x^2+x y^2\\ \dot{y}&=y-y^2+2x^2\end{align}$$
which implies
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{y-y^2+2x^2}{x^2+x y^2}$$
Now if you do a qualitative analysis on this equation, you can see that the terms with highest degree on the numerator and denominator are $2x^2$ and $xy^2$, respectively. Which implies that $\frac{dy}{dx}$ at large values of $x,y$ and $x\neq 0$ will be zero.

So the problem was, you did a quick judgement and generalized a local trend to a global one. These diagrams are self-evident:

[image: pp]

Comment: As much as I know it is usual to define a **basin of attraction** for an attractor trajectory which stands for the domain in which the attractor pulls the neighbor flows inward. Even if you have a sink (stable fixed point) its effect might disappear at some far distances. So if my example does't work at the infinity, it obviously works for the range that has been plotted. There is two attractor paths in the plot, they may loose their attraction property as one goes far,

Comment: I accept that, and their basin of attraction will shrink to zero at the infinity and both of them become parallel to the $x$ axis there. But still they are present and there must be equations for them particularly in the interval that I have plotted the field flows and they have very important effect there.

Comment: @Sh.A. for that, you can analyze the system for small values. e.g. linearization of the system around an equilibrium point and getting the eigenvectors of the linearized system will show you the direction of stream lines around that point.